# Responsive Navigation w/ hamburger menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am very new to trying to understand javascript and I cannot seem to figure out how to code my hamburger menu to open up and show my navigation in mobile view. I am able to have my main navigation in desktop and the look of what I want for mobile and tablet in those views but the button does not work. I have some javascript in there that I tried out but it didn't work. I'll put everything in a snippet so that maybe someone can help me understand this. Thank you!

```js
$('.toggle').click(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('nav ul').slideToggle();
});



$(window).resize(function () {
    "use strict";
    if ($(window).width() > 780) {
        $('nav ul').removeAttr('style');
    }
});
```

```css
/*   Start global   */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial, tahoma;
  list-style: none;
  /*    outline: 1px solid brown;*/
}

/*   End global   */



header {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 500px;
}

/*   Start navigation bar   */

nav {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #222;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555
}
.logo {
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
.logo img {
  height: 55px;
}
.list-item {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-top: 17px;
}
.list-item li {
  float: left;
  padding: 13px 13px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}
.list-item li a {
  color: #EEE;
}
.list-item li:hover {
  background-color: brown;
}

/*   End navigation bar   */





/*   Start nav bar for small screens   */

.icon {
  display: none;
}
.toggle {
  float: right;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #EEE;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #EEE;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*   End nav bar for small screens   */

/*   Start media query   */

@media (max-width: 775px) {
  .icon {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #111;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  }
  .list-item {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
    background-color: #222;
    display: none;
  }
  .list-item li {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    float: none;
  }
 
 .result-iframe {
    border: 0;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}


/*   End media query   */

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link href="about.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="about.js" rel="alternate">


</head>


<body>



 <header>
      <nav>
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/ec/13/a7/ec13a753972c254761be4d9d5666d341.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="icon">
          <span class="toggle">☰</span>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-item">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Categorys</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you linking to your jquery file/cdn?

Comment: in my head section: I can edit the snippet so that I include that. My apologies. @MadGab

Comment: Remember you need to start your javascript code after the DOM has loaded. You can put your javascript at the end of the body or better yet use $(document).ready(function(){ <your javascript or initialization function goes here>});

Comment: and it's not working on a phone/tablet? The hamburger menu seems to work fine in Chrome. Try adding a link to a jQuery CDN as the last line in your body element and see if it works...

Comment: @alfredo Thank you! This helped me out! I didn't realize that I had to put it at the end of the body. I truly appreciate your help!

Comment: @Cakers You are welcome. That's one way to ensure the DOM has all loaded before the javascript gets called. If you use jquery, a more accepted way is to use $(document).ready() and if you are not using jquery you can use window.onload. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added `jQuery` and it seems to be working fine.

```js
$('.toggle').click(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('nav ul').slideToggle();
});



$(window).resize(function () {
    "use strict";
    if ($(window).width() > 780) {
        $('nav ul').removeAttr('style');
    }
});
```

```css
/*   Start global   */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial, tahoma;
  list-style: none;
  /*    outline: 1px solid brown;*/
}

/*   End global   */



header {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 500px;
}

/*   Start navigation bar   */

nav {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #222;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555
}
.logo {
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
.logo img {
  height: 55px;
}
.list-item {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-top: 17px;
}
.list-item li {
  float: left;
  padding: 13px 13px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}
.list-item li a {
  color: #EEE;
}
.list-item li:hover {
  background-color: brown;
}

/*   End navigation bar   */





/*   Start nav bar for small screens   */

.icon {
  display: none;
}
.toggle {
  float: right;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #EEE;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #EEE;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*   End nav bar for small screens   */

/*   Start media query   */

@media (max-width: 775px) {
  .icon {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #111;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  }
  .list-item {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
    background-color: #222;
    display: none;
  }
  .list-item li {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    float: none;
  }
 
 .result-iframe {
    border: 0;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}


/*   End media query   */

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link href="about.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="about.js" rel="alternate">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>


<body>



 <header>
      <nav>
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/ec/13/a7/ec13a753972c254761be4d9d5666d341.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="icon">
          <span class="toggle">☰</span>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-item">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Categorys</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>


</body>
</html>
```